# git pull + build проекта

Tags: git, build, git-pull

Всем привет, хотелось бы уточнить имеется ли возможность написания скрипта, который запулит изменения и забилдит проект, ПРИМЕР: данная функция есть в TeamCity (сначала выкачать изменения из нужной ветки, а потом забилдить проект), но к сожалению, кол-во агентов это сделать не позволяют, а проектов несколько, хотелось бы автоматизировать этот процесс, вручную процесс довольно долгий и муторный.

Comment: Да, имеется такая возможность. Более того, есть целый подход в разработке ПО, который (примерно) именно в этом и состоит. Называется continuous delivery.

Comment: Копайте по слову `Jenkins`.